# Android Firebase push message in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have tried this code, but something happened unexpectedly. I can see a push message on my phone, but I can’t see the log in Android Studio. I think the method `onMessageReceived` isn’t working. Why did this happen?

My code follows.

`MyFirebaseMessagingService.java`

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
    private boolean isVibrator = true;
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
            //vibrator();

        }

        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: "+remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            vibrator();
        }

    }

    private void vibrator(){
        if(isVibrator){
            Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            long[] pattern = {200,1000,150,1500,100,2000,50,3000}; 
            vibe.vibrate(pattern, -1);
        }
    }

    private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        vibrator();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)//.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
                .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

       /* PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) this.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wakelock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK |
                PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "TAG");
        wakelock.acquire(5000);*/

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

`MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.java`

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        Log.d(TAG, "send Server");
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: did you add the service to AndroidManifest.xml:
`<service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.google.Firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
</intent-filter>
</service>`

Comment: Oh,, I already did it. But, I had mistake. I put that not under application....... It operating well!!! Very thank you!!!